# Google Maps API - image slideshow in infowindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm looking for a way to create a image slideshow in the infowindow of the Google Maps API.

This is the code I'm using -

```
var slideIndex = 1;

$(function() {
        initializeMaps();
    });

    function initializeMaps() {

        fetch('./get_locations.php').then(response => {
          return response.json();
        }).then(data => {

          var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 6,
            center: {lat: 48.208411, lng: 16.373471}
          };

          var spots = data;
          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
          var markers = [];      
          var md5array = [];
          var contentHtml = "";

          for (var i=0;i<spots.length;i++) {
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

            md5array = spots[i].md5.split(',');

            if(md5array.length > 1) {
                contentHtml = "";

                for(var j=0;j<md5array.length;j++) {
                    contentHtml += '<a href=show_image.php?md5="'+ md5array[j] +'"><img class="mySlides" src="https://www.whatever.com/pics/locations/'+ md5array[j] +'.jpg" width="350px" height="350px" alt="'+ spots[i].location +'" title="'+ spots[i].location +'"></a>';
                }
                contentHtml = '<div>' + contentHtml + '<br><button class="slideshow-button slideshow-button-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button><button class="slideshow-button slideshow-button-right" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button></div>';
            }
            else {
                contentHtml = '<div><a href=show_image.php?md5="'+ spots[i].md5 +'"><img src="https://www.whatever.com/pics/locations/'+ spots[i].md5 +'.jpg" width="350px" height="350px" alt="'+ spots[i].location +'" title="'+ spots[i].location +'"></a><br></div>';
            }

            var spotMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(spots[i].lat,spots[i].lng),
                map: map,
                zIndex: 1,
                icon: '/pics/misc/pin.png',
                spotContentHtml: contentHtml,
                location: spots[i].location
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function() {
                showDivs(slideIndex);
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(spotMarker, 'click', function () {
                console.log(this.spotContentHtml);
                infowindow.setContent(this.spotContentHtml);
                infowindow.open(map, this);
            });

            markers.push(spotMarker);
          }
          var mc = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {gridSize: 40}); 

        }).catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    }

    function plusDivs(n) {
        showDivs(slideIndex += n);
    }

    function showDivs(n) {
        var i;
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
        if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
        if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].style.display = "none";  
        }
        x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    }
```

Basically I'm first checking if I have more than 1 image per location. If not, I just want to show this one image. If there is more than 1 image I'd like to create a slideshow. It works fine for locations with multiple images, but once I click on the marker where I only have one image I'm getting the following error message -

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
at showDivs (locations.php:213)
```

I assume it happens due to an incorrect order of how I'm calling the domready and click events, but unfortunately I can't figure out how to solve it.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: A single image doesn't have `class="mySlides"`, therefore `x` is empty, therefore `x[0]` is `undefined`, and thus `x[0].style` results in the error.

Comment: yes, I understand where the issue is coming from, but not sure how to prevent it.

Comment: You can either not call `showDivs` in the first place if there's only one image, or you can put `if (x)` in front of the style command, or you can add the class to the single image in your contentHtml.

Comment: Thanks! That solved my problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue comes (I think as I didn't test it) from this line:

```
x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
```

The below code won't cause trouble, because you tell your script to loop for until `i` is not smaller anymore than `x.length`. So if `x.length` is zero, nothing will happen and your script won't try to access properties of an inexistant object.

```
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i].style.display = "none";  
}
```

But if you do `x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";` without checking whether `x[slideIndex-1]` corresponds to anything, you will have issues.

**Solution**:

You could first check on the length of `x` like:

```
if (x.length) {

  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
}
```

And also make sure that `x[slideIndex-1]` exists, ie. that it doesn't end up trying to apply the style to `x[-1]` item, for example.

Comment: Yes, that's it. Thank you very much! :)